# What is a Patternful Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Patternful Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Patternful Words™ | Not Patternful Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| double | float |
| beautiful | ugly |
| America | United States |
| igloo | snow |
| hour | second |
| house | lawn |
| frank | funk |
| pollster | polls |
| runs | puns |
| grunt | hunt |
| crazy | hazy |

- **Open Hint:** The pattern is dictated by a logical predicate of the form "A Patternful Word™ is a word that contains `<condition 1>` **OR** `<condition 2>`." The list above is divided roughly into two halves; the first half shows you examples that satisfy `condition 1`, and the second half shows you examples that satisfy `condition 2`. There are two words in the entire list that satisfy both conditions.
- **Open Hint 2:** The rule applies to any string made up of English alphabet characters, and is not necessarily restricted to only English words (e.g. I could use the rule against some random string like "asdfslkj").
- **Open Hint 3:** White spaces do not count towards word lengths in this puzzle.

Comment: I guess this is similar to a Bongard problem but with words instead of images. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bongard_problem

Comment: @happystar Yes, it is similar to a Bongard problem. It is also related to how words are pronounced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Open Hint 1, we know that the rule is that the word contains `condition 1` OR `condition 2`, and that the first half of the list shows `condition 1`, and the second half shows `condition 2`.

Condition 1:

> The word contains at least 50% vowels, by letter count.
>
>  double = 3/6
>  beautiful = 5/9
>  America = 4/7
>  igloo = 3/5
>  hour = 2/4
>  house = 3/5
>
>  None of the right side words, "float, ugly, United States, snow, second, lawn, funk, polls, puns, hunt, hazy" qualify, with the closest being "United States" with 5/12.

Condition 2:

> The word contains the letter **R**
>
>  The second half of the left side words "frank, pollster, runs, grunt, crazy" all qualify.
>  None of the right side words have an "R".

From Open Hint 1, two of the words satisfy both conditions:

> America and hour

Why these strange conditions?

> The author of the puzzle is BearAqua, whose name satisfies both conditions.